# Apache POI for Excel: Setting the cell type for an entire column

Tags: java, grails, apache-poi

The code below works fine to setting up the cell type as 'text' for the entire column for .xls file, however this doesn't work for .xlsx file.

I am using Grails, Apache POI 3.11

How to achieve this? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
        DataFormat fmt = workbook.createDataFormat();
        CellStyle textStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        textStyle.setDataFormat(fmt.getFormat("@"));
        worksheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(0, textStyle);
```

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work"?

Comment: Are you working with an existing workbook or creating a new one with apache-poi?

Comment: I added a separate thread, please refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35486392/apache-poi-excel-columnstyle-not-setting-text-category-for-pre-populated-value